# Debounce Until in Rx.Net

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I have 2 streams of events:
1. Stream of mouse drag and drop events (drag start ... drag end ... drag start ... drag end)
2. Stream of key press events ('a' ... 'b' .... 'c' .... 'd')

I need to combine into a stream that only contains events from the second streams (so only key presses) but it needs to filter out all key presses that occur between a drag start and drag end, *except for the last one*.

So if the sources are like this:

```
... Start ............... End .............. Start .............. End
```

and

```
...........'a'...'b'...'c'.......'d'...'e'..........'f'....'g'.......
```

The result should be like this:

```
...........................'c'...'d'...'e'..........................'g'
```

Is something like this possible using Rx.net in C#?

Comment: The snark in me wants to just answer yes without providing how. :)

Comment: Any yet, you have provided an answer, and a good one too :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. Answer first, then explanation:

```
public static class X 
{

    public static IObservable<T> GatedDebounce<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<bool> gating)
    {
        var finalStream = gating
            .StartWith(false)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Publish(_gating => source.Publish(_source => Observable.Merge(
                _source
                    .Window(_gating.Where(b => b), _ => _gating.Where(b => !b))
                    .SelectMany(o => o.LastAsync()),
                _source
                    .Window(_gating.Where(b => !b), _ => _gating.Where(b => b))
                    .Merge()
            )));
        return finalStream;
    }

}
```

Then, given an `IObservable<T>` representing your values, and an `IObservable<bool>` representing where drags start and stop (true meaning drag-start, and false meaning drag-end), you would call it like this:

```
var throttledStream= valueStream.GatedDebounce(gateStream);
```

---

**Explanation**:

To understand it better, let's throw out the `Publish` calls, and break it up into pieces:

Piece 1,

```
source
    .Window(gating.Where(b => b), _ => gating.Where(b => !b))
    .SelectMany(o => o.LastAsync())
```

This `Window` function means call means we start a sub-set observable (or window) whenever gating emits true, and end that window whenever gating emits false. From that window, we select the last item, if it exists. This will only be emitted when the window closes.

Piece 2,

```
source
    .Window(gating.Where(b => !b), _ => gating.Where(b => b))
    .Merge() //Equivalent to .SelectMany(o => o) if you prefer
```

This `Window` function does the opposite: Start a window whenever gating emits false, and end it whenever gating emits true. From that window we emit everything when it arrives.

Put these two together with `Merge` and you get 90% of the way to your solution. The rest:

- The `.StartWith(false)` is to make sure we open a window when you initially start the observable, otherwise values that happen before the first gating item are lost.
- The `DistintUntilChanged()` is a cheap way to make sure our gates are t, f, t, f and never two of the same value in a row, which would cause two simultaneous windows to open.
- The `Publish` calls are good practice to prevent multiple subscriptions. You can find better explanations for that in some other Q&A's on here.

Comment: Not directly related to the question but can you recommend a good and *updated* online reference guide to Rx.net? There are fantastic refereces to RxJS which I use almost daily but for some reason Rx.net is not nearly as well documented.

Comment: I would recommend introtorx.com and reactivex.com. Neither are that up to date, but they both provide 95% of what you need.